# Error certificado SSL deploy con heroku y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

Tengo una cuenta en heroku, tengo errores de certificados SSL chrome me muestra lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: estas detras de un firewall???

Answer (score 1):

El error que presentas es la carga de Mixed-Content (HTTP y HTTPS) cuando HSTS está activado. Para ello, cambia todas las direcciones que empiezen por http:// a https:// y se solucionará el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

ese error no esta relacionado a un certificado SSL. Es un nuevo control de seguridad agregado en chrome en la ultima actualización.

Revisa en tu código que scripts estas incluyendo y ve la posibilidad de manejarlos de manera local (Descargándolos e incluyéndolos desde la carpeta de tu proyecto)

Saludos